# Laravel date parse exotic format with Carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I'm having problems parsing this date format with Carbon on laravel

```
2020-04-24 12:01:44.138126109 +0000 UTC m=+567667.142114821
```

my code reads

```
$generated = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u P T', '2020-04-24 12:01:44.138126109 +0000 UTC m=+567667.142114821');
```

Im having this error

```
InvalidArgumentException 

The timezone could not be found in the database
```

Comment: What's the content of `$stream[1]`?

Comment: edited to clarify

Comment: If it's not important, perhaps you can limit to `2020-04-24 12:01:44` as that seems to be the only part Carbon can parse successfully

Comment: It's not related to Carbon, createFromFormat is a DateTime method. Here I see 3 chunks `+0000`, `UTC` and  `m=+567667.142114821` but only 2 expected formats `P` and `T` and `m=+...` does not match any of those formats. Plus `u` expect only 6 digits. The input must match the format you gave. All other input must be handled separately regarding what they mean in your app.